# Magento 2 : Add Custom Tooltip to Shipping Methods On Checkout Page

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I need to display the custom tooltip for shipping methods on checkout page using magento 2.1.

Comment: Hi have you got the shipping method tool tip ?